# Disabled back button and time Handler

Tags: java, android

I have a game quiz, and if a user's answer is wrong a popup screen pops up and stays on screen for 3 seconds. I do this with Handler. Since the game is time limited, they come up with solution to press back button to remove popup from the screen :) and move along. So I disabled the back button for that popup activity. BUT, now I have another problem. It seems that my Handler count time from the last click, so if I click back button on that popup screen Handler count time from that click. If I click it again, it starts from beggining. I've tried to click it 10-12 times and my popup screen was on for half a minute. :) And that's not good. How to make my popup be on for 3 seconds no metter if click back button or not during his time on?

My popup class:

```
public class WrongAnswer extends Activity{

    TextView wrong;
    String correctAnswer, correct;

    public final int delayTime = 3000;
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();

    public void onUserInteraction(){
        myHandler.removeCallbacks(closePopup);
        myHandler.postDelayed(closePopup, delayTime);
    }
    private Runnable closePopup = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            finish();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //do nothing
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.wrong);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        if(extras !=null) {
           correct = extras.getString("correctAnswer");
        }

        inicijalizujVarijable();

        myHandler.postDelayed(closePopup, delayTime);

            }

    private void inicijalizujVarijable() {

        wrong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWrong);
        Typeface pogresanFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Bebas.ttf");
        wrong.setTypeface(pogresanFont);
        Wrong.setText("Wrong answer!\nCorrect answer is:\n\n" + correct);
    }
    }
```

Comment: is WrongAnswer the popup?

Comment: You're resetting the timer on any user interaction. This is intentional? Seems to describe the behaviour you are talking about here -> " It seems that my Handler count time from the last click"...

Comment: @blackbelt yes, this is the popup class.

Comment: @KenWolf no, it is not intentional. I want just to show my popup and after 3s to kill it, no metter what user is clicking.

Comment: onUserInteraction means when the user interacts. pressing the back button counts as interacton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this:

```
public void onUserInteraction(){
    myHandler.removeCallbacks(closePopup);
    myHandler.postDelayed(closePopup, delayTime);
}
```

It's resetting your handler on any interaction, which results in the behaviour you describe.

As a side note, it seems rather heavy to dedicate an `Activity` to this functionality, I think you'd be better off using a `Dialog` or similar.

Comment: Tried a dialog, but low customization options. :) Thanks, I will try this. It seems that this is a leftover from my other popup. Did not see it at all.

Comment: You can totally customise a dialog to look like however you want (custom content view, full-screen just like an activity, etc.), consider it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can show popup as Dialog and setCancelable() to false.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable(boolean)